# Creating\rendering a heatmap not showing up

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, heat-map

I am having a problem rendering a heatmap. I am sure the heatmap is created but it doesnt display when I replace or add a renderer.

```
  var TF = new FeatureLayer({
    url:"https://services3.arcgis.com/1pxU2hJU9ZszJDcX/ArcGIS/rest/services/Young_Adult_Treatment_Facilities/FeatureServer/0",
  })


  //apply HM to layer      
  function apply(result){
    console.log("applying")
   TF.renderer = result.renderer;
   };


  var heatmapParams = {
    layer: TF,
    basemap: map.basemap
  };


document.getElementById("butt").addEventListener("click", heatmapRendererCreator.createRenderer(heatmapParams).then(apply));
```

Whenever I call the apply function to create a renderer the point layer disappears.

Here's a codepen:

https://codepen.io/segev-salman/pen/eaEbRv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must pass the `view` object to the `heatmapParams`:

```
var heatmapParams = {
  layer: TF,
  view: view
};
```